# Django: how to use AWS access key without revealing it in source code

Tags: django, amazon-web-services

I'm following tutorial from
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/hls-playback.html#how-hls-ex1

It works great, but the access key is visible to user in the source code. How can I go about hiding access key from the user using Django?

Tutorial puts the access keys visible in the source code:

```
var options = {
accessKeyId: $('#accessKeyId').val(),
secretAccessKey: $('#secretAccessKey').val(),
sessionToken: $('#sessionToken').val() || undefined,
region: $('#region').val(),
endpoint: $('#endpoint').val() || undefined
}
var kinesisVideo = new AWS.KinesisVideo(options);
var kinesisVideoArchivedContent = new AWS.KinesisVideoArchivedMedia(options);
```

I think I need to set
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY variables in settings.py, but how can I use them without revealing them to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should compute the video URL on the backend and pass that to your template, like so: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-adds-support-for-hls-output-streams/

The AWS docs shouldn't be recommending that you stick your secret key into JavaScript.  This is a good catch on your part, but other people may not be so wise.  You should report the documentation to AWS.  (There is a "Provide Feedback" link at the bottom of all pages in the AWS docs.)

Additionally, to not check your AWS key/secret into your repository, have your settings load these from a config file that is not checked into the repository or from environment variables.  Check out [django-environ](https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for a library that does this really well.

Comment: Thank you! With you help I was able to process url in the backend and submit it from views.py securely. I needed to add region_name, aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key parameters to boto3.client().
P.S. I submitted feedback to AWS :)

Comment: That [AWS docs page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/hls-playback.html#how-hls-ex1) doesn't suggest that you stick your access/secret keys in the page's JavaScript. It suggests that they be entered by the user. Or, of course, you could authenticate the user against a backend that sends temporary STS credentials down to the web page.

Answer (score 1):

Many ways - I like python-decouple:

settings.py:

```
from decouple import config
    
AWS_SECRET_KEY = config('AWS_SECRET_KEY')
SOME_ENV_VAR = config('SOME_ENV_VAR')
...
```

.env:

```
AWS_SECRET_KEY = 'the_secret_key'
SOME_ENV_VAR = 'some_value'
...
```

Then be sure to include `.env` in your `.gitignore` file.

Comment: The question is asking about an AWS example that uses the key and secret in javascript code; I misread it at first too

Comment: This was anyway useful information to me. I will use python-decouple to fetch config variables from files instead, to prevent them being on the repository. Thank you.